# How to hide menu item on specific page

Tags: html, jquery, css, ejs

I am trying to create webpage using NodeJS, express and I am using ejs templating engine.I have one menu item in navbar `add` now when user clicks  on add it should  go to another page which shows from to add some data.What I want is when user clicks on add menu item it should not be visible on next page to which its linked with.

Below is my code:

**nav.ejs**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
<div class="container-fluid">
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Studious</a>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a id="ad" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/add">Add</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

**index.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#ad").click(function(){

      $(this).hide();
  
   });
});
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.use("/public", express.static('public')); 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

app.get('/',(req,res) => {

    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/add',(req,res) => {

    res.render('add');
});

app.listen(port,() => console.log(`App is running at ${port}`));
```

Someone let me know how can I achieve desired result.

Answer (score 1):

1. you need to pass current url to ejs pages.
2. In the nav.ejs page on condition bases you need to add the a href tag of /add.

example:

in **server.js**

```
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.render('index', {
       currentUrl: req.originalUrl
    });
});

app.get('/add',(req,res) => {
    res.render('add' {
       currentUrl: req.originalUrl
    });
});
```

in **nav.ejs**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <%if (currentUrl != '/add') { %>
            <a id="ad" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/add">Add</a>
        <% } %>
    </li>    
</ul>
```